# Periodically run Wordpress plugin independently of user interaction?

Tags: php, wordpress, events, plugins, cron

I was wondering if there are any tutorials or guides on how to schedule the running of Wordpress plugin at specific time intervals or specific hours in the day, without having the running of the plugin being dependent on the visits of the websites by users.

I know that is the case with Cron jobs. Is there any way to schedule events without having the visiting of the web site being dependent on users and their tendency to visit the website?

Comment: The easiest way might be to set up a real (as in system, not WP) cronjob to make a request to your WP. You can also run wp-cron.php with php-cli, and add a cronjob for that.

Comment: @janh2 do you have any good links on how to set this up?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167238/running-wp-cron-on-multisite-the-right-way has a nice discussion on it using wp-cli. https://pressjitsu.com/blog/wordpress-cron-cli/ discusses it with bare php (you'll probably not need the python wrapper they go to in the end).